# Angular search filter(Consists array of strings)

Tags: angular, typescript

html:

```
<input matInput placeholder="Search" value="" formControlName="searchbar">
```

ts:

```
typesOfShoes: string[] = ['Boots', 'Clogs', 'Loafers', 'Moccasins', 'Sneakers'];
```

I need to display the data which matches the array data.

Comment: html consists:<input matInput placeholder="Search" value="" formControlName="searchbar">

Comment: Are you wanting to filter an ngFor list or just filter a array in memory using the text from your filter input?

Comment: yes, billy_comic. not multi select dropdown, input search bar and the array data need to filter based on search box value, need to implement select all and desellect all  typesOfShoes=[
            {id:1,name:'Boots'}, 
            {id:2,name:'Clogs'}, 
            {id:3,name:'Loafers'}, 
            {id:4,name:'Moccasins'}, 
            {id:5,name:'Sneakers'}
        ]; this data should be displayed with checkboxes need to capture the selected checkboxes using reactive form control.

Answer (score 0):

string[] = ['Boots', 'Clogs', 'Loafers', 'Moccasins', 'Sneakers'];

let searchKey;(value which you have to serch)

let Search = string.find((a) =>a.includes(searchKey);

you get the match value in serch variable

Answer (score 0):

> HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="autoComplete"
      placeholder="Search" [formControl]="searchControl">
   <mat-autocomplete #autoComplete>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let shoe of filteredShoes" [value]="shoe"> {{shoe}} </mat-option>
   </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

> TS

```
  searchControl = new FormControl();
  typesOfShoes: string[] = ['Boots', 'Clogs', 'Loafers', 'Moccasins', 'Sneakers'];
  filteredShoes: string[];

  ngOnInit() {
     this.searchControl.valueChanges.subscribe(searchSrting => {
        this.filteredShoes = this.getSearchResult(searchSrting).slice();
  });

  getSearchResult(searchString: string): string[] {
     return this.typesOfShoes.filter(x => x.toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase()))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for input, I am trying to reproduce something like input search textbox and select all and deselect all with checkboxes of items using reactive forms module.